# For each crosstab column, highlight maximum value

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, conditional-statements, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

I'm trying to highlight the maximum value in a Crystal Reports crosstab column, per column, i.e. show the best performing salesman in each month.

It seems like a fairly basic requirement, but I can't figure it out!  The Highlighting Expert would seem to be the obvious answer, but it only works if you have defined criteria (e.g. Gross Sales > 120,000), and I'm not interested in highlighting the Totals at the end of the columns/rows....I just want the highest value row per column.

Comment: Just thinking....is this something I could do with a couple of For loops?  I know there are functions for getting the number of columns/rows, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more difficult than it needs to be...

Add this text to the summary field's "Tool Tip Text" conditional-formatting formula:

```
// this assumes that there is a Total column and that it is the left-most column.

Numbervar max:=0;
local Numbervar col;

// exclude (left-most) total column
for col := 1 to GetNumColumns-1 do (

    local numbervar value := GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, col, CurrentSummaryIndex);
    if value > max then max := value;

);

ToText(max,"#");
```

Then add this text to the *same* field's "Style" conditional-formatting formula:

```
Numbervar max;

If GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 0) = max Then
    crBold
Else
    crRegular
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

By the way, I tweaked the tooltip formula a little to work how I wanted; I have Sales Value on the X axis and Month on the Y axis.

Final tweaks looks like this:

`// this assumes that there is a Total and that it is the bottom row.

Numbervar max:=0;
local Numbervar row;

// exclude bottom total row
for row := 0 to GetNumRows-2 do (

    local numbervar value := GridValueAt (row, CurrentColumnIndex, CurrentSummaryIndex);
    if value > max then max := value;

);

ToText(max,"#");`

Comment: Nice solution to this problem