# In Crystal Reports, how to dynamically format a cross-tab on a gradient?

Tags: crystal-reports, gradient, conditional-formatting

This has already been asked elsewhere including [Crystal Reports Cross Tab Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767737/crystal-reports-cross-tab-conditional-formatting)   however I found it hard to discover an answer to this question and also found that the answers out there are very specific.

**How does one dynamically and automatically format the cells within a Cross-Tab in Crystal Reports to show a gradient between any two colours?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a generic bit of code that should be easy to modify and apply for any two-colour gradient scale.

Select the cell in your Cross-tab you want to modify and choose Format Field. Go to the Border tab. Click on the x+2 button next to Background. Enter the following code in the formula field, and save.

```
local Numbervar max := 100; -- Put in the highest possible value here. I'm using percentages so this goes up to 100.
local Numbervar min := 0; -- Put in the lowest possible value here. I'm using percentages so this is 0.

// Reference Yellow 255,231,63 -- Pick colour one here, for the low end of the scale. This is yellow. You'll need the RGB and plug them in below
local Numbervar c1r := 255; // red value for the first colour
local Numbervar c1g := 231; // green value for the first colour
local Numbervar c1b := 63; // blue value for the first colour

// Reference Green 105,192,98 -- Pick colour two here, for the high end of the scale. This is green.
local Numbervar c2r := 105; // red value for the second colour
local Numbervar c2g := 192; // green value for the second colour
local Numbervar c2b := 98; // blue value for the second colour

local Numbervar cRed;
local Numbervar cGreen;
local Numbervar cBlue;

if currentfieldvalue >= max then color(c2r,c2g,c2b)
else if currentfieldvalue <= min then color(c1r,c1g,c1b)

else
(
if c1r = c2r then cRed := c1r
else if c1r > c2r then cRed := Floor(c2r + (c1r-c2r) * (1-(currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min)))
else cRed := Floor(c1r + (c2r-c1r) * (currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min));

if c1g = c2g then cGreen := c1g
else if c1g > c2g then cGreen := Floor(c2g + (c1g-c2g) * (1-(currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min)))
else cGreen := Floor(c1g + (c2g-c1g) * (currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min));

if c1b = c2b then cBlue := c1b
else if c1b > c2b then cBlue := Floor(c2b + (c1b-c2b) * (1-(currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min)))
else cBlue := Floor(c1b + (c2b-c1b) * (currentfieldvalue-min)/(max-min));

color(cRed, cGreen, cBlue)
)

color(cRed, cGreen, cBlue)
```