# How to Highlight the Max Value in a Crosstab Row

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a crosstab report in Crystal Reports. The rows are trips that are taken throughout the day (eg. trip 1000, trip 1010, trip 1020, etc). The columns are the stops along that trip (eg. Franklin, Hollywood, Sunset, Santa Monica, Melrose, etc.). The summarized value in the crosstab is the average load at each stop. For each row, I'd like to highlight the stop with the highest value, so that the schedulers who use the report can find it easier. any ideas on how to do this?

I searched this site and found someone asking the same question but column-based instead of row-based. I figured I could just adapt that formula for my needs, but one of the functions found in it, 'GetNumColumns' does not register with my version of crystal. how can that be? I have Crystal Reports 11.5

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Link to the question that was similar to yours? More importantly, can we see your code?

Comment: link to the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418114/crystal-reports-for-each-crosstab-column-highlight-max-value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `highlighting Expert` to change the color of font and background in a crosstab rows.

Just `right click` on the field and select the `highlighting Expert` there for the required condition you can apply color for both font and background

Comment: this option only allows one to set a constant as the required condition, as opposed to setting the max for a row as the required condition, which is what I need. it seems to be impossible with this program :(

Comment: Max  value is the one that you set while giving the value... this option works.. at value you give the maximum value so that when the condition is met then color is changed